# File "main.py", line 30, in ban await member.ban(reason=arg) AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'ban'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

In this line of code, I have a problem.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(member: discord.Member, arg):
     await member.ban(reason=arg)
     await bot.send(f'User {member} has been banned')
```

The error:

```
File "main.py", line 30, in ban
    await member.ban(reason=arg)
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'ban'
```

I don't have any ctx. What's it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all of your commands, you have to have `ctx` as your first parameter. In yours, you have `member` as your first parameter. `ctx` gets passed into the command as the first parameter when the command is called, so, `member` is actually `ctx`. Also, `bot.send` doesn't exist, you should use `ctx.send` instead. So this would be the ideal code (with a few changes):

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason):
     await member.ban(reason=reason)
     await ctx.send(f'{member} has been banned')
```

Answer (score 0):

All commands take always `ctx` (the `Context`) as the first argument, also there's no such things as `bot.send`

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, arg):
     await member.ban(reason=arg)
     await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been banned')
```